# Symfony2 command and tcpdf whiteoctober

Tags: symfony, command, tcpdf

I use symfony and I have installed whiteoctober TCPDF with success.
It works if I use it in a controller, my PDF is generated.

However I want to use it in a command.
So I have a command called "CronInvoicesCommand" in a command folder and of course I have this error:

> Attempted to call method "get" on class "OandP\boBundle\Command\CronInvoicesCommand" in C:\wamp\www\OandPlocal\src\OandP\boBundle\Command\CronInvoicesCommand.php line 187. Did you mean to call: "getAliases", "getApplication", "getDefinition", "getDescription", "getHelp", "getHelper", "getHelperSet", "getName", "getNativeDefinition", "getProcessedHelp", "getSynopsis"?

So my question is how can I load all those method in a command.
Thank you se much for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use a container aware commmand :

```
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Command\ContainerAwareCommand;

class MyCommand extends ContainerAwareCommand
{
    protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output)
    {
        $em = $this->getContainer()->get('doctrine')->getEntityManager();
        // ...
```

Comment: I already have the use... I replace the get () by getcontainer() : $pdf = $this->getContainer("white_october.tcpdf")->create('vertical', PDF_UNIT, PDF_PAGE_FORMAT, true, 'UTF-8', false); but I sill have an error : Attempted to call method "create" on class "appDevDebugProjectContainer

Comment: So sorry, it works with getContainer(). Thank you so much for help.

Comment: can you validate any answer please?

Comment: $this->get(******) is for Symfony 2.6 and older versions

Answer (score 1):

Probably you are trying to get a service from a container similar to the controller method get. In a Command you can access to the container with the getContainer() method, so try to substitute something like:

```
$this->get('service_name');
```

with

```
$this->getContainer()->get('service_name');
```

More info [here in the doc](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/console/console_command.html#getting-services-from-the-service-container).

Hope this help

Comment: I still have an error : Attempted to call method "create" on class "appDevDebugProjectContainer

Comment: So sorry, it works with getContainer(). Thank you so much for help.